# Integration with fraction of trigonometric functions

Tags: integration, analysis, trigonometry

I have a trouble with solving
$$
\int \frac{\sin^2 (x)}{\sin(x) + \cos (x) + 2} dx
$$

This can probably be solved by some form of substitution, but it didn't lead me to some clear enading or further steps.

Comment: [Try this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_formula#The_tangent_half-angle_substitution_in_integral_calculus) - "the world's sneakiest substitution" (M.Spivak)

Comment: Do you know half angle substitution?

Comment: How did you convert the denominator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the sustitution $u=\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$.
  We get, after some manipulation $$8\int\frac{u^{2}}{u^{6}+2u^{5}+5u^{4}+4u^{3}+7u^{2}+2u+3}du=8\int\frac{u^{2}}{\left(u^{2}+1\right)^{2}\left(u^{2}+2u+3\right)}du$$
 which can be rewrite, using partial fraction as $$8\int\left(\frac{1-2u}{8\left(u^{2}+1\right)}+\frac{2u+3}{8\left(u^{2}+2u+3\right)}+\frac{u-1}{4\left(u^{2}+1\right)^{2}}\right)du$$
 can you get it from there?